# How do I save the "Many" side of a Many to One if I only have the id of the "One" side?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have two entities with a one to many relationship. Call them EntityOne and EntityMany.

I want to save an EntityMany to the database.
I don't have an instance of EntityOne but I know the required entity_one_id.

Is there a way to save EntityMany without retrieving an instance of EntityOne from the db?

I don't want to do anything with the saved EntityMany. I just want to save it.

The only way I've been able to save EntityMany in this situation is to retrieve the EntityOne from the db, do a $entity_many->setEntityOne($entity_one) and then persist EntityMany.

That works but it seems like an unnecessary query for EntityOne when all the db needs is the id.

I tried simply instantiating a new EntityOne() and setting the id (I had to add a setter for the auto-generated integer id) and then using that unsaved instance but Doctrine was not happy with several errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityManager has a method "getReference" - you can use it to achieve your goal. It should look something like that:

```
$entityRef = $em->getReference('EntityOne', $entityOneId);
$entityMany->setEntityOne($entityRef);
// ...
```

Look here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#proxy-objects

Comment: Another thought. How about the reverse? Let's say I have an instance of EntityMany. I have not accessed its getEntityOne() method so, with lazy loading, EntityOne has not been loaded. Is there any way of knowing the id of its EntityOne other than actually loading it with $entityMany->getEntityOne()->getId() ?

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634190/how-do-you-get-an-associated-entitys-id-without-loading-the-associated-entity.

Comment: Thanks again. Doctrine is pretty smart.