# Doctrine: Why $entity->ManyToOneRelation->getId() does fire a query to database?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a User class with referrer field:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"detach"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="referrer", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $referrer = null;

    public function getReferer(){
        return $this->referrer;
    }
}
```

What have I read is that since Doctrine 2.2 when I call `$user->getReferer()->getId()` I should get referenced id without doctrine firing additional query.

But in my case, doctrine is fetching whole entity from database.
What am I doing wrong?

I use symfony 2.7.1 and I run echo `\Doctrine\ORM\Version::VERSION` to check doctrine's version.

(`$user->getReferrer()` isn't firing any additional query yet.)

**EDIT**:

How I test it:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$referrer = $user->getReferrer();
//Until there one query is executed by security(?) to fetch authenticated user.
//Referrer is not yet initialized.

$this->addFlash('info', 'Referrer id: '.$referrer->getId());
//Now second query was fired. And $refferer is now initialized.

return array('data' => $referrer); //return $refferer object for twig dump.
```

Twig dumps something like this for code without `getId()`:

```
User {#1184 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: false
    #id: "2"
    #referrer: null
}
```

And this for code with `getId()` used on `$referrer`:

```
User {#1184 ▼
    +__isInitialized__: true
    #id: 2      
    #referrer: null
}
```

Comment: Where did you read such a thing?  Cause it ain't right.

Comment: @Cerad, First I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139970/getting-only-id-from-entity-relations-without-fetching-whole-object-in-doctrine There is no version mentioned, then I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634190/how-do-you-get-an-associated-entitys-id-without-loading-the-associated-entity where 2.2 version of doctrine is mentioned

Comment: No fair linking to my own post.  Something else in your code must be accessing the referee object.  Perhaps it is being serialized?

Comment: @Cerad I updated my post with test code.